# HipHop Runtime options explanations and resources

Tags: php, .htaccess, hhvm

There are several configuration options that can be found [here](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Runtime-options). But it looks heiroglyphs to me, not all, but I do not know what options are essential to keep a application running. I have a basic understanding on `.htaccess` when I am running a php application, like setting an `index.php` as an entry point, the `hhvm.hdf` same as `htaccess` where all things are optional.

I have a hunch that the most important thing to configure here is the default file, `index.html, index.php, index.htm`, and the sources path?, not sure of the sources, bec. I don't know if the sources are default in current directory.

If some could explain some of the important configuration, then it will a lot helpful.

**UPDATE:**
Let say I am trying to create an `api`, what configuration should I have in the `hdf` file.
The api make use of `index.php` as entry point and the other part `uri` will be parsed to have a decent `get` api

Comment: Do you have any specific problem to ask OR just want a general opinion as answer?

Comment: i think more of general opinion, i know this is a bit odd, but there aint good resources out there.

Comment: To be clear, you're looking for the minimum configuration needed to (safely) run an app using hhvm, and (optionally) an explanation of what some nice-to-have set options would be? Can you perhaps describe what the app needs from another server? (rewrites, simple/digest auth, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

Getting hhvm running took a lot of trial and error since the documentation is currently largely non-existent. I, however, managed to get it working with a moderately complex app that involves a number of rewriting rules.

You have to configure a VirtualHost section in the .hdf file the represents your site. Under that you create a RewriteRules section which can contain any number of rewrite rules. One gotcha that tripped me up was the Conditions block under a RewriteRule that specifies exceptions when the rule should not be applied.

The configuration is a bit involved. I wote an [article about configuring hhvm](http://miles-by-motorcycle.com/fv-b-8-656/adventures-in-configuring-and-running-facebook-s-hiphopvm--hhvm--jit-compiler-for-php.html).